# Write list of list to csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a function :

```
writer = csv.writer(open('dict.csv', 'ab'))
for row in izip_longest(finald, finalp, namebi, main):
    writer.writerow([x.encode("utf-8") for x in row])
```

**finald**, **finalp** and **namebi** are lists.

**main** is a list which has many other lists of same size.

I want to encode the data in utf-8 too. All the data in one row is related to each other so it can't go off sync.

I want csv output like :

```
finalp[0],finalp[0],namebi[0],main[0]key[0],main[0]key[1] .....
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for row in zip(finald, finalp, namebi, main):
    writer.writerow([x.encode("utf-8") for x in row[:-1]] +
                    [x.encode("utf-8") for x in row[-1]])
```

I use `zip` instead of `izip_longest`. The latter would need a fill values because the default `None` cannot be encoded and written to a file.